# CS:GO item lookup with steamkit2 api

Tags: c#, steam, steam-web-api

I am trying to get items from a trade to send to a database. The only issue is that the data im receiving isn't giving me what I need. I am using JesseCar96's steambot for TF2 and have reprogrammed it for `CS:GO`. When I run the following code I have access to 4 main things:

```
foreach (var asset in theirItems)
{
    Console.Write(asset.assetID);
}
```

I have access to the item's **appID**, **assetID**, **contextID** and **currencyID**. From there I want to lookup the item name, quality, value on the market etc. Unfortunately there's not a lot of documentation for `steamkit`. Does anyone know the APIcall I need to make?